# How to hide unhide webview in android

Tags: android, webview, hide

I develop application which has webview and imageview(as toogle button), if button clicked then webview will be closed, if button clicked again, then webview will be opened. Is it possible in android? see the circle red with up arrow which can hide and unhide above banner
My reference like this application [image]

Comment: You can set webView.setVisibility(View.GONE); and toggle it on button click..

Comment: you developed  the whole thing and you have problem change the visibility of a View?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

for hide the webview

```
mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

for show the webview

```
mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: okay thanks, my fault is using VIEW.INVISIBLE, now is working

Answer (score 2):

Just take all of your view which you want to hide in one `Linearlayout` having orientation set to vertical and visiblity to visible and gone as below.

```
webView.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
```

and

```
webView.setVisiblity(View.Visible);
```

where webview is initialized by you xml's Webview.

I hope this works for you.

Thanks

Comment: okay thanks, my fault is using VIEW.INVISIBLE, now is working

Answer (score 1):

you use setvisibility() method  are follow...

1. if hide webview

   **webview.setvisibility(view.GONE);**
2. if visible webview  then

   **webview.setvisibility(view.visible);**

   that's solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setVisibility()` method to achieve that.. `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to make the webview visible else `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `setVisibility(View.GONE)` to make it vanish

Comment: okay thanks, my fault is using VIEW.INVISIBLE, now is working –  Agoeng Lauw

Answer (score 0):

If using XML, as easy as:

> android:visibility="invisible"