# How to control webview overlay when it is full screen?

Tags: android, ios, webview, ibm-mobilefirst

For one of my project, I need to load the external page from inside my worklight (hybrid mobile) app (replace page screen). For android and IOS, I am going to use webview overlay. I need to load the page for full screen, hence gives the full control to external server page. However, I am not sure how to link my app to the server page.
For example, if I need to close the webview overlay, how do I do that? The entire screen is server page. How do I control it from there? Is it even possible to close the webview overlay when the overlay is full screen?
Is there other solutions? I need to load the serve page inside my worklight application, not through browser, full screen, and be able to go back to my app.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the "Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications" training module and look at the accompanying sample project? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_advanced

Comment: @IdanAdar I read it. But the example in the project only gives webview overlay for a partial view. Of course you could close the webview overaly because you still have some part of your page to control the webview overlay. I want the webview to be on full screen. Just wondering is it a way to close the webview when it is at full screen. I assume that any local file is not seen on the page. Or could it ever be done?

Comment: I don't think so. You need to have the user somehow interact with it; re-consider your UI.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help to understand how and where exactly you are loading the WebView. The solution will depend on it.

Are you loading the WebView:

- In the application's activity on app launch?
- From a Cordova plug-in?

Here are some questions that may help:

- [closing webview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305612/closing-webview-in-android)
- [How to hide unhide webview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282570/how-to-hide-unhide-webview-in-android)