# Webview set visibility to INVISIBLE or GONE dose not work in android

Tags: android, webview

in below code i used a webview, but when i set visibility to invisible or gone, it dose not work and always is visible, why?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_item_fade_in"
        android:numColumns="3" >
    </GridView>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show how do you set visibility

Comment: What you say is not possible. Post the code where you set the WebView as Gone

Comment: <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

Comment: I also use this code but dose not work: webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: and webView.setVisibility(View.Gone); dose not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide unhide webview in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282570/how-to-hide-unhide-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I've found my answer.

I override `onPageFinished` method, and in that I used `setVisibility(View.Visibile)`, so after some seconds it runs and `WebView` goes visible. So be careful about threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_item_fade_in"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this code works for grideView but dose not work for webView

Comment: clean the project and try again sometimes it will help... select project then go to **option** from toolbar select **clean**...

Comment: make your **Relative Layout** `width`  as `fill_parent` or `wrap_content`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93460/discussion-between-sud-and-user1615184).

Answer (score 0):

in xml

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"    
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  />
```

in code:

```
Webview webview =  (Webview)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and please show where you set visibility  ?